# how to bind two input to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

As seen below script:- function is run when 'id= input1' is enter. I need to add another id eg. id= input2, as input2 is enter, function is run again..

```
  $('.input1' ).bind("focus blur change keyup", function(){
     ....
  };
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to bind the same function for these elements to all four of the following events: focus, blur, change, keyup?  What is this function actually doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For classes (`.myclass`):

```
$('.input1, .input2').bind("focus blur change keyup", function(){ .... });
```

For IDs (`#myID`):

```
$('#input1, #input2').bind("focus blur change keyup", function(){ .... });
```

Comment: +1, doesn't get much simpler than this.. though this 1 line of code could be extremely expensive and slow down your site dramatically if those classes are assigned to several nodes ;)

Comment: the Answer is wrong as you are binding to two classes called input1 and input2.  OP specifically asked to bind to an element ID

Comment: Well I used his example because it had classes, I will edit and put both now

Comment: @Ghostoy Was this meant to be on my answer or on the original question?

Comment: @Fred To the original question and a complement to your answer.

Comment: @debrajsy See this document for more jQuery selectors: api.jquery.com/category/selectors

Answer (score 1):

you can specify in a comma separated string like

```
$("selector1,selector2,...,selectorN").bind(
```

REF: [jquery multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind two inputs by ID you must use the `#idName` instead of `.idName`.  Notice the difference: the period is for element class names and the number sign is to define an element ID, within the jQuery Selector

Here is some reference

[ID Selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

[Class Selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Next jQuery Selectors can be bound by multiple selectors by separating them with a comma.

```
$('#input1, #input2').bind("focus blur change keyup", function(){ .... });
```

However I do not believe you would really want to bind each of these events to the same function.

You stated "function is run when 'id= input1' is enter."  I'm assuming you mean on focus of the elements.  Which if my assumption is true you would want to do this

```
$('#input1, #input2').bind("focus", function(){ .... });
```

or

```
$('#input1, #input2').focus(function(){ .... });
```